# Do updates in MongoDB in the same record make the db grow?

Tags: mongodb

I'm doing an update to the same record various times in my web server (a player id incrementer), so my question is if this repeating update eventually makes the MongoDB database  grow larger ( due to transaction logs, for example), or if the size of the db pretty much remains the same.

If the db actually grows larger because of this, how can I prevent that situation?

Thank you!

EDIT:

More details about this situation:

The update statement is as follows:

```
db.usergen.update({ userprefix: userPrefix }, { $set: { number: userIdNumber } },
    { upsert: true }, function(err, saved) {});
```

This update works always on the same record. The only thing that changes in this record is the "number".

Comment: That update could make the document shift if you are changing from a small string/number/whatever to a large version of it, what kind of value are you expecting?

Comment: a simple integer something from 1 to 10.000, for example. the number is incremented every time this update is called

Comment: Hmm that shouldn't cause a movement I believe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB has, at most, an oplog and journal. The oplog is a capped collection of a fixed size as such it will never just grow out of control and the journal has a contained amount of space (normally 3GB).

If the document requires to be moved on disk due to growth then yes, the DB can grow in size causing fragmentation within your deleted and free lists.

This presentation is good at explaining this concept: http://www.10gen.com/presentations/storage-engine-internals

As for avoiding that situation, it all depends on what queries you are performing and what updates you are committing. There is no single way to fix the problem and without knowing more about your problem I can only direct you to places.

One consideration, if you are making continous, regular, updates which require document movement would be to use power of 2 sizes allocation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/#usePowerOf2Sizes

However, most of the time it is a case of tweaking the schema and queries to be more performant, i.e. not creating so much redundancy within subdocuments etc.

There is one other place you could see a problem which is within the `mongod` logs. If you create excessive logging of queries that touch your `mongod` servers then you could be seeing your logs using up all your space, however, you can solve this problem by limiting just how much log is written or http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/